# difference between str(dict) and json.dumps(dict)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

What is the difference between the output of `str(a dictionary)` and `json.dumps(a dictionary)`? If I print them, they look the same. Their attributes (as per `dir`) also seem to be identical (see below). Yet I know there must be a difference. Could you please explain it to me?

```
import json

aDictionary= {"first": 42, "second":21}
s = str(aDictionary)
j = json.dumps(aDictionary)
s == j # returns false
dir(s) == dir(j) # returns true
```

Comment: `str(dict)` does not produce valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I experienced that but I would like to understand better the difference between two things that look otherwise very similar.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name. And if you print the results you would see the difference; from `str`: `"{'first': 42, 'second': 21}"` and from json: `'{"first": 42, "second": 21}'`. Notice the double quotes around the strings for keys.

Comment: Of *course* `dir()` returns the same list of attributes and methods. Both `s` and `j` are strings. That says nothing about the *contents of those strings*.

Comment: s == j # returns false because in string composed of characters as both are string but with different commas sequence.  from str: "{'first': 42, 'second': 21}" and from json: '{"first": 42, "second": 21}'. See the commas sequence are different in both so obviously the comparison will bring false. For two strings need to equal only if they have matching characters at corresponding places.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`str(aDictionary)` (as well as `repr(aDictionary)`) produces a *Python representation* of your dictionary. This representation is helpful for debugging *and nothing more*. For the built-in types such as dictionaries and strings, you'll be given a representation that is valid *Python* syntax. Python syntax and JSON syntax may look similar, but are **not the same thing**.

- Python uses single and double quotes for string literals. JSON only allows double quotes.
- Python Unicode strings use `\<single letter>`, `\xhh`, `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh` escape sequences to encode Unicode codepoints; the latter form is used for non-BMP codepoints. JSON uses a smaller range of `\<single letter>` escapes as well as the `\uhhhh` form, and encodes UTF-16 surrogate pairs for non-BMP codepoints (so two `\uhhhh` sequences per codepoint).
- Python uses `None` objects, JSON uses `null` to as a special "doesn't exist" sentinel value.
- Python uses `True` and `False` as boolean values, JSON uses `true` and `false`.
- Python dictionary keys can be any hashable type, JSON only supports strings.

So `str(dictionary)` will *not* produce valid JSON output, most of the time; only if all your keys and values are BMP strings with at least one single quote in the value could you end up with a document that can also be parsed as valid JSON.

In terms of your specific example, note that `str(aDictionary)` produces a document with *single quotes*; `json.loads()` can't load this document as that's not valid JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> aDictionary = {"first": 42, "second":21}
>>> str(aDictionary)
"{'first': 42, 'second': 21}"
>>> json.loads(str(aDictionary))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Never use `str(pythonobject)` as a serialisation. Although the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can load a reasonable number of Python built-in types from a string representation, it is a lot slower than using JSON for the same job, or a more sophisticated [data persistence format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) if JSON doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: great and accurate answer.